# Why does zipfile.is_zipfile returns True on xlsx file?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, zip

I am using `is_zipfile` to check if it is a zipfile before extracting it. But the method returns True on excel file from a StringIO object. I am using Python 2.7. Does anyone know how to fix this? Is it reliable to use `is_zipfiile`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [Microsoft's XLSX Structure overview doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd926896%28v=office.12%29.aspx),

> Workbook data is contained in a ZIP package conforming to the Open
>   Packaging Conventions

So, `.xlsx` files are actually zip files only. If you want not to consider them as a zip file, you may have to exclude with an if condition like this

```
if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] != ".xlsx" and zipfile.is_file(filename):
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because `xlsx` is actually a valid zip file.

See  also:

- [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)
- [The Microsoft Office XML formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats)

Comment: Thanks alecxe, I take thefourtheye as the answer as it is more detailed.